# Trouble Creating Math for Accurate Division of Two Lists of Doubles with Custom Carryover

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making an idle/click game in unity, and have a custom format that I'd like all the numbers in the game to display as. K for thousands, M for millions, B for billions, etc. See below example from a game called Tower of Heroes.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daWW1.jpg)

The displaying of these numbers and units works great. However, where I am running into an issue is with my decision to have arbitrarily large numbers in the game. I did not want to be limited by the constraints of double, and wanted the challenge of coming up with my own solution. I was able to do so, and even get most math operations to work with my solution. Addition, subtraction, multiplication, and exponents all work well enough. But I cannot figure out the logic/math for division...

So, I am using a list of doubles for each of my game variables.
Example: `List<double> money = new List<double>();` would be a list containing the money the player currently has. Every position is limited to 0-999. Position 0 represents the "1's", position 1 the thousands, position 2 the millions, etc, with the list growing as large as it needs to. So if we had:

```
List<double> money = new List<double>()
{
    10,  //1's
    50,  //thousands (K)
    200  //millions (M)
         //etc.
};
```

that would be $200,050,010, or in my game's notation: 200M050K. (I only display the largest unit, or sometimes the largest two units)

For example, here is the addition method I have working:

```
     //SuperAdd
public List<double> SuperAdd(List<double> baseValue, List<double> valueBeingAdded)
{
    //declairing a new list to house the result
    List<double> resultValue = new List<double>();

    //making copies to not affect originals
    List<double> baseValueCopy = baseValue;
    List<double> valueBeingAddedCopy = valueBeingAdded;

    //increase the # of tiers in our result list until it matches the largest of the two being added
    while (resultValue.Count < Mathf.Max(valueBeingAddedCopy.Count, baseValueCopy.Count))
    {
        resultValue.Add(0);

        //if needed adjust the size of the two lists being added together so they match
        if (valueBeingAddedCopy.Count < baseValueCopy.Count) valueBeingAddedCopy.Add(0);
        if (valueBeingAddedCopy.Count > baseValueCopy.Count) baseValueCopy.Add(0);

    }

    //add all the respective tiers together
    for (int i = 0; i < resultValue.Count; i++)
    {
        //add all the tiers together
        resultValue[i] = baseValueCopy[i] + valueBeingAddedCopy[i];           
    }

    //check for any carry overs needed (>=1000)
    for (int i = 0; i < resultValue.Count; i++)
    {
        //where this is true we need to carry over to next tier
        if(resultValue[i] >= 1000)
        {
            //check if we are on the last existing tier
            if(i + 1 == resultValue.Count)
            {
                //add an empty tier
                resultValue.Add(0);
            }

            //calculate how many thousands need to be carried over, and what the remainder is
            double nextTierAdder = Math.Floor(resultValue[i] / 1000);
            double currentTierRemainder = resultValue[i] % 1000;

            //apply both
            resultValue[i] = currentTierRemainder;
            resultValue[i + 1] += nextTierAdder;                
        }
    }

    //remove any empty blanks from the ends of the resultValue list
    for (int i = resultValue.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if (resultValue[i] == 0) resultValue.RemoveAt(i);
        else break;
    }

    //return resultValue
    return resultValue;
}
```

So, what I'm looking to achieve is a similar method for division, pseudo code:

```
    public List<double> SuperDivide(List<double> baseValue1, List<double> baseValue2)
{
    //code goes here

    return result;
}
```

What I have so far is some junk code as a placeholder until I figure out a correct solution that will return a List.

```
        //SuperDivide result = bv1 / bv2
//this is currently only useful when the values are near one another in size
public double SuperDivide(List<double> baseValue1, List<double> baseValue2)
{
    double result;

    //check if one input list is way bigger than the other, and return a simplified result
    //the 100 is because double has a max of 1.7x10^308, each position in our lists holds 1x10^3
    if(baseValue1.Count - 100 > baseValue2.Count)
    {
        result = Math.Pow(10, 300);
        return result;
    }
    if(baseValue2.Count - 10 > baseValue1.Count)
    {
        result = 0.00000000001; //arbitrary small # that isn't quite 0
        return result;
    }

    //get the stopping position for the for loops (clamped at 5 due to double having a precision of 15 digits)
    int stopPos1 = baseValue1.Count - Mathf.Clamp(baseValue1.Count, 1, 5);
    int stopPos2 = baseValue2.Count - Mathf.Clamp(baseValue2.Count, 1, 5);        

    //empty strings to hold the #'s
    string bv1String = "";
    string bv2String = "";

    //create a string of the largest digits in bv1
    if (stopPos1 > 1)
    {
        //create a string of the largest digits in bv1
        for (int i = baseValue1.Count - 1; i >= stopPos1; i--)
        {
            if (i == baseValue1.Count - 1)
            {
                bv1String = baseValue1[i].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                if (baseValue1[i] < 10) bv1String = bv1String + "00" + baseValue1[i].ToString();
                else if (baseValue1[i] < 100) bv1String = bv1String + "0" + baseValue1[i].ToString();
                else bv1String = bv1String + baseValue1[i].ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    else
    {
        //create a string of the largest digits in bv1
        for (int i = baseValue1.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (i == baseValue1.Count - 1)
            {
                bv1String = baseValue1[i].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                if (baseValue1[i] < 10) bv1String = bv1String + "00" + baseValue1[i].ToString();
                else if (baseValue1[i] < 100) bv1String = bv1String + "0" + baseValue1[i].ToString();
                else bv1String = bv1String + baseValue1[i].ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    //create a string of the largest digits in bv1
    if (stopPos2 > 1)
    {
        //create a string of the largest digits in bv2
        for (int i = baseValue2.Count - 1; i >= stopPos2; i--)
        {
            if (i == baseValue2.Count - 1)
            {
                bv2String = baseValue2[i].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                if (baseValue2[i] < 10) bv2String = bv2String + "00" + baseValue2[i].ToString();
                else if (baseValue2[i] < 100) bv2String = bv2String + "0" + baseValue2[i].ToString();
                else bv2String = bv2String + baseValue2[i].ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    else
    {
        //create a string of the largest digits in bv2
        for (int i = baseValue2.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (i == baseValue2.Count - 1)
            {
                bv2String = baseValue2[i].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                if (baseValue2[i] < 10) bv2String = bv2String + "00" + baseValue2[i].ToString();
                else if (baseValue2[i] < 100) bv2String = bv2String + "0" + baseValue2[i].ToString();
                else bv2String = bv2String + baseValue2[i].ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    //create numbers for the input lists
    double bv1Double = double.Parse(bv1String);
    double bv2Double = double.Parse(bv2String);

    //adjust for one being bigger than the other, only by relative amount though
    //only needed when one of them has 6+ tiers
    if (baseValue1.Count > 5 && baseValue2.Count > 5)
    {
        if (baseValue1.Count > baseValue2.Count)
        {
            bv1Double *= Math.Pow(1000, baseValue1.Count - baseValue2.Count);
        }
        else if (baseValue1.Count < baseValue2.Count)
        {
            bv1Double *= Math.Pow(1000, baseValue2.Count - baseValue1.Count);
        }
    }

    //calculate result
    result = bv1Double / bv2Double;

    return result;
}
```

Questions:

(1) If anyone can point me in the right direction for the math/logic of the special division, I can probably handle the coding.

(2) Would it be appropriate to make another post / add to this one my other math methods, looking for code suggestions? (I'm a self-taught novice and know there are a lot of improvements I could make to these methods)

Comment: Why not use `BigInteger`?

Comment: I think the first question should be, why do you use a double? Isn't the use of non-whole numbers arbitrary if you expand towards billions? If so, then use a long 
(max = 9,223,372,036,854,775,807), a ulong (max = 18,446,744,073,709,551,615) or even a BigInteger (no max) like canton7 suggested, however i believe that a long will probably suit your needs.

Comment: That is definitely an option. When I started out BigInteger looked intimidating, but if I can't figure out my custom solution, I'll likely go that route.

Comment: I chose double because I needed something with decimals for use with exponents and division, and double has the highest precision. Any single type (other than BigInteger or similar) won't work since I'm planning to have stupidly big numbers (1e1800, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep your custom formatting and not switch to BigInteger,  there might be a viable way to divide by using your existing addition and subtraction operators.

Since your values are stored in a list of integers, you should run through that list for each number and perform long divison. 
I'm on my phone so I can't provide a code example, but the logic is somewhat straightforward.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division

Let's say the calculation is 300/20

First step is to find the first subset of 300 that is equal to or larger than the 20. 
That will be 30.

Then you find the qoutient and calculate the remainder, which is 1 and  10 respectively.

You then append the next number  from the 300 (which is a 0) to the remainder (10). This will give you 100. 
Then you do the same thing resulting in a qoutient of 5 and remainder of 0.

The remainder being zero means that the calculation is complete. 
Then you append all the qoutients you've calculated and you have the result ("1" + "5" = "15")

For finding the qoutient and remainder you can use Euclidean Division that also only uses your existing addition and subtraction operators. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm
N / D = (Quotient, Remainder)

Algorithm:

```
R = N, Q = 0
while(N > D)
{
    R= R - D
    Q ++
}
```

Wikipedia has some nice visualisations and probably explains it clearer. 
The main takeaway is that you should be able to implement this algorithm using your existing operators while only using addition and subtraction.

Comment: This worked, thank you! A bit disappointed I didn't see such an obvious solution myself. Going to post the code below with a follow-up question. I'll be marking your post as the answer.

Comment: Glad to help. Sometimes its best going back to basics. 
If you post your code I'll try to answer your follow-up question.

Answer (score 0):

With the suggestion from Nicklas, I was able to put together the following chunk of code. I did a fair bit of testing and am fairly confident it is mostly / all correct. The follow-up question was going to be that during testing I found that operations resulting in a very large answer (ex: 10 trillion / 5) would take a long time. After thinking for a few minutes I came up with a decent solution for massive time savings. Now it will spit out stupidly big results instantly.

```
        //assumes both inputs are positive and > 0
public List<double> SuperDivide(List<double> numerator, List<double> denominator)
{
    //here we are going to adopt the notation used on the wiki page for long division
    //inputs are numerator/denominator
    //outputs are (Q,R) quotient and remainder

    //create and set the Q to 0
    List<double> quotient = new List<double>
    {
        0
    };

    //create a list of value 1
    List<double> one = new List<double>
    {
        1
    };

    //declairing a new list to house the result
    List<double> resultValue = new List<double>();

    //empty strings to hold the #'s
    string denomString = "";
    string remainderString = "";

    //create and set the R = N
    List<double> remainder = new List<double>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numerator.Count; i++)
    {
        remainder.Add(numerator[i]);
    }

    //getting a starting value
    string compareResult = WhichIsBigger(remainder, denominator);

    //calculate Q and R: while R >= D
    while(compareResult =="A" || compareResult == "Equal")
    {
        //get the multiplier we can use to save calcs on big # results (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx / yyyy)
        List<double> testResult = DivTester(remainder, denominator);

        //create a var for D * X, where X is the testResult
        List<double> denomMult = SuperMultiply(denominator, testResult);

        //Q = Q + X
        quotient = SuperAdd(quotient, testResult);

        //R = R - DX
        remainder = SuperSubtract(remainder, denomMult);

        compareResult = WhichIsBigger(remainder, denominator);
    }

    //if R = 0, return Q
    if(remainder.Count == 1 && remainder[0] == 0)
    {
        return quotient; 
    }

    //else return Q + (R/D)
    else
    {
        //get the stopping position for the for loops (clamped at 5 due to double having a precision of 15 digits)
        int stopPosR = remainder.Count - Mathf.Clamp(remainder.Count, 1, 5);
        int stopPosD = denominator.Count - Mathf.Clamp(denominator.Count, 1, 5);

        //create a string of the largest digits in R
        if (stopPosR > 1)
        {
            for (int i = remainder.Count - 1; i >= stopPosR; i--)
            {
                //starting tier (largest #)
                if (i == remainder.Count - 1)
                {
                    remainderString = remainder[i].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    if (remainder[i] < 10) remainderString = remainderString + "00" + remainder[i].ToString();
                    else if (remainder[i] < 100) remainderString = remainderString + "0" + remainder[i].ToString();
                    else remainderString = remainderString + remainder[i].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = remainder.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                //starting tier (largest #)
                if (i == remainder.Count - 1)
                {
                    remainderString = remainder[i].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    if (remainder[i] < 10) remainderString = remainderString + "00" + remainder[i].ToString();
                    else if (remainder[i] < 100) remainderString = remainderString + "0" + remainder[i].ToString();
                    else remainderString = remainderString + remainder[i].ToString();
                }
            }
        }

        //create a string of the largest digits in D
        if (stopPosD > 1)
        {
            for (int i = denominator.Count - 1; i >= stopPosD; i--)
            {
                if (i == denominator.Count - 1)
                {
                    denomString = denominator[i].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    if (denominator[i] < 10) denomString = denomString + "00" + denominator[i].ToString();
                    else if (denominator[i] < 100) denomString = denomString + "0" + denominator[i].ToString();
                    else denomString = denomString + denominator[i].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = denominator.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (i == denominator.Count - 1)
                {
                    denomString = denominator[i].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    if (denominator[i] < 10) denomString = denomString + "00" + denominator[i].ToString();
                    else if (denominator[i] < 100) denomString = denomString + "0" + denominator[i].ToString();
                    else denomString = denomString + denominator[i].ToString();
                }
            }

        }

        //create numbers for divsion of R/D
        double remainderDoub = double.Parse(remainderString);
        double denomDoub = double.Parse(denomString);

        //adjust for one being bigger than the other, only by relative amount though
        //only needed when one of them has 6+ tiers
        if (remainder.Count > 5 && denominator.Count > 5)
        {
            if (remainder.Count > denominator.Count)
            {
                remainderDoub *= Math.Pow(1000, remainder.Count - denominator.Count);
            }
            else if (remainder.Count < denominator.Count)
            {
                denomDoub *= Math.Pow(1000, denominator.Count - remainder.Count);
            }
        }

        resultValue.Add(remainderDoub / denomDoub);

        resultValue = SuperAdd(resultValue, quotient);

        return resultValue;
    }
}
```

And the DivTester method:

```
        //I'm sure there are much more effecient ways to determine this multiplier...
private List<double> DivTester(List<double> rem, List<double> denom)
{
    //declairing a new list for testing, starting value of 1
    List<double> ten = new List<double>()
    {
        10
    };

    //create and set the dCopy = denom
    List<double> dCopy = new List<double>();
    for (int i = 0; i < denom.Count; i++)
    {
        dCopy.Add(denom[i]);
    }

    //create and set the testerPass = 1
    List<double> testerPass = new List<double>()
    {
        1
    };

    //getting a starting value
    string compareResult = WhichIsBigger(rem, dCopy);

    while(compareResult == "A")
    {
        dCopy = SuperMultiply(dCopy, ten);

        //check and see if it is still successfull
        compareResult = WhichIsBigger(rem, dCopy);

        //if it passes, multiple testerPass by ten
        if (compareResult == "A")
        {
            testerPass = SuperMultiply(testerPass, ten);
        }
    }

    //return the largest multipler (10^X) that can be safely used
    return testerPass;        
}
```